# how to remove origin access control via AWS console?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I create a  origin-access-control on my cloudFront via AWS console but now, I need create this by my CI/CD (so cloudFormation). I have this error `"Resource of type 'AWS::CloudFront::OriginAccessControl' with identifier 'xxx' already exists."` So I want remove this via console before redeploy via cloudFormation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find finaly: **CloudFront** > **Origin access**

`https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v4/home?region=us-east-1#/originAccess`